# Negative to positive number range in regex in bash scripting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, regex

I am trying to make a regex expression that will validate a number that is in the range of -100 to 100.
I made this regex expression: (^-[1-100]* |^[0-100]*) but it doesn't work as expected.

I am looking for a number pattern in a string, not just a number by itself.

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

check(){
input="test1.txt"
while read -r line; do
a=( $line )

for i in "${a[@]:1}"; do
if [[ "$i" =~ (^-[1-100]*|^[0-100]*) ]]; then
echo "$i"
fi
done
done < "$input"
}
check
```

the input file:

```
add $s0 $s1 $s3
sub $s0 $s1
addi $s1 $s2 76
lw $s2 -50($s2)
```

the actual result: add $s0 $s1 $s3 sub $s0 $s1 addi $s1 $s2 76 lw $s2 -50($s2)

the expected result: 76 -50($s2).

Comment: Why do you absolutely want a regex for that? A regex is a good tool... for some cases but not all. Bash has numeric comparison operators.

Comment: One misconception in your writing: `[0-100]` will not be parsed as a range from 0 to 100 like you expect, but as 3 items: `0-1`, `0`, `0`. `0-1` will indeed be the range from `0` to `1`, so all added `[0-100]` is the same as `[0100]` which is just `[01]` or `(0|1)`. `[1-100]` will in fact be the exact same thing. `[..]` is for character classes so things in it are understood character by character. Also the `*` applies to the token before it and means the token can appear never or once or multiple times (unbounded), so your [0-100]* means in fact: empty string, or unlimited amounts of`0`or`1`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[0-100]` isn't a range of integers; it's a set of characters that happens to include a range `0-1` (so matches `0` or `1` or `0` or `0`).

To match the range of integers `-100` to `100`, you could use:

- a decimal digit `[0-9]`; optionally followed by
- a second decimal digit `[0-9]`

or

- the sequence `100`

all preceded by an optional sign. So

```
^[-+]?([0-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

Ex.

```
while read num; do 
 [[ $num =~ ^[-+]?([0-9][0-9]?|100)$ ]] && echo "$num is valid" || echo "$num is invalid"
done
-101
-101 is invalid
-100
-100 is valid
-83
-83 is valid
22
22 is valid
100
100 is valid
102
102 is invalid
^C
```

Comment: when I use this expression I don't get any results

Comment: @David then there are likely other issues with your code: I only tried to answer the "Negative to positive number range in regex in bash scripting" part

Comment: @steel Your pattern will match `-00`. You may like to fashion it more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473595/2943403